# Django template page display wrong date time format (using DataTable)

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, datatables

My script return a list of date time with a format like '2016-11-09 06:42:53.028447+00:00'.  However, on the front end the order of month and date changed to '2016-09-11'

Template:

```
'<td>{{ entry.datetime|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s"}}</td>'
```

when I start manage.py on my local machine it display correctly.  So i'm wondering there is a setting that I mis-configured.

setting.py

```
USE_L10N = False
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y m j, H:i:s.u'
```